# Reprojecting .shp layer in QGIS3 to current CRS not working

Tags: qgis

Working in QGIS for the first time and I currently have a map that has all my points and polygons in the correct places. However, my polygons are projected in EPSG:3726 and my points are currently projected in EPSG: 4269.

Where I am running into an issue is that 4269 works in degrees not meters so I can't build buffers around my points without issues. When I change the projection of my points to match the projection of my polygon the points move WAY far away from where they were and are useless. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you have two files one is point and one is polygon, what is the format? shape file ?

Comment: Yes, both are shapefiles one is a polygon and the other is a set of points.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably assigning a new projection (ie. setting a new CRS without transforming the coordinate to this new crs). what you need to do is to Reproject your layer to your new CRS (either by using the 'Reproject layer' from the processing toolbox or using Export>Save feature As... when you right click on your layer

Comment: I just tried using the reproject tool. it did the same thing. shifted the reprojected point way far away from where they should be

Comment: @MikeThompson this should work. Load the points and polys into a project together with their native CRS. Then Export>Save Features As on the points and change the CRS here as you save to 3726. They should then come back into the map physically in the same place but referencing the new CRS